# Migrate SQL Azure across Azure regions and subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-migration

We have SQL Azure databases currently in the SouthEast Asia region under an older subscription (Subscription 1).

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to migrate the database server & associated databases into a new Azure subscription (Subscription 2) and into the SouthEast Australia region, while **maintaining the same server name**?
2. Will this migration change the existing schema, i.e. will it add tracking columns to the existing database tables?

Thanks in advance,
Shailen

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using the SQL Database REST API's.  There is a sample of this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn479912.aspx).